# Library not importable

Tags: android, gradle, import, material-design

I am trying to use the [BetterSpinner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707) library.

I have added it to my grade file like that:

```
  compile ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext', module: 'library'
    }
```

Gradle syncs without any issue.

In the class I usually get the suggestion by Android Studio to import the library I am using in the code. 
But Android Studio did not. 
So I copied the import by myself:

```
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.R;
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner;
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner;
```

Android Studio grey that code out and marks "R" and "BetterSpinner" red.

Do I miss some important step?

Comment: did you try to clean caches and run 'gradle idea' to apply new dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import `com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.R;` from your imports and add import for the R file of your package.

its something look like `import com.example.jublikon.myapplication.R;`

then clean your project and rebuild